# Can I call a class have only instance variable a wrapper class?

Tags: java, class, wrapper

I have a class which only contains instance variables, getter  and setters, something like:

```
public class MyClass {
@Getter @Setter private String bla;
@Getter @Setter private String blabla;
@Getter @Setter private Date dateBla;
}
```

Can I call it a `Wrapper-class`? Or do such classes have a `specific name`? So far I am only familiar with primitive wrapper classes.

Comment: It is just a Java class

Comment: A wrapper for what? If the answer to question is yes, then all classes are wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapper class is definitely the wrong term.

More correct terms would be:

- **Model class or Domain Model**, if it's used to represent from the underlying domain in the system but note that it's also likely an example of the [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) antipattern.
- [**Data Tansfer Object**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) if the reason it contains no functionality is that it mainly exists to *move* data.
- [**Java Bean**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) to stress that it conforms to that convention, but that's not entirely correct, as a JavaBean is allowed to have other methods.
- [**Value Object**](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/value_object_vs_data_transfer), the *misuse* of a term for something else that occurred in a popular book (Core J2EE Patterns) and, although corrected in later editions, keeps popping up.

Comment: Data Transfer Object should be the right term in my case, since i use the class to return a response to a SOAP request. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't call it a wrapper class. A wrapper class sits on top of the main class / primitive and provides additional features.

For example  `Integer` class is a wrapper over the primitive `int` because it provides additional functionality when compared to what an int provides. It also provides additional behavioral properties (like the ability to be inserted into collections).

Your class is just a plain java class.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://way2java.com/java-lang/wrapper-classes/

> As the name says, a wrapper class wraps (encloses) around a data type
>   and gives it an object appearance. Wherever, the data type is required
>   as an object, this object can be used. Wrapper classes include methods
>   to unwrap the object and give back the data type. It can be compared
>   with a chocolate. The manufacturer wraps the chocolate with some foil
>   or paper to prevent from pollution. The user takes the chocolate,
>   removes and throws the wrapper and eats it.
>
> [1]: http://way2java.com/java-lang/wrapper-classes/

Generally speaking, a wrapper class is any class which "wraps" or "encapsulates" the functionality of another class or component. So no you can't call the class mentioned in the question a wrapper class.